# Is there an Eslint rule that enforces the use of optional chaining or && checks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

In the pursue of checking for an undefined value in a deeply nested object(These objects are potentially undefined in the context of async data), I'm using optional chaining to mitigate that, but it's easy to forget about checking If an object is undefined.

There is this Eslint rule which just prefers optional chaining over `&&`s

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/prefer-optional-chain.md

But I wonder if there is a rule that enforces the use of optional chaining.

**Edit**: Adding more context where this is useful.

Comment: I notice you have `typescript` tagged here. I'd expect that if an object is typed as potentially undefined, you'd have a compilation error from the typescript compiler. Is that not sufficient? Edit: the reason I brought up typescript rather than looking into eslint rules is this feels like the exact thing TS helps with.

Comment: If such a thing existed it would force you to put optional chaining everywhere(e.g. `document?.querySelector(something)`). It would harm readability once followed or would require additional resources for fighting it.

Comment: @Nick Yes typescript helps with that, but the issue presents with async data(eg: REST API), deeply nested objects are not guaranteed to not be undefined.

Comment: @skyboyer That's what I'm afraid of, I thought about an Eslint rule intelligent enough to target only async data, but I'm not sure if something like this is possible to build.

Comment: If the properties of the data are potentially undefined, you should correctly type it to reflect that. That way you can rely on the compiler itself instead of a lint rule.

Comment: That's a great solution, that I should keep in mind next time. I don't have the momentum to refactor the typing atm, especially that it is autogenerated and quite big.